# How to implement apearing 3D text in video?

Tags: video, after-effects, editing

First of all I like to mention I have some knowledge in After Effects, as I created "Dragonball Z" effects for fun few years back. I also have some basic knowledge in Photoshop to create 3D texts, visuals ect.

I am looking for a way to create a intro video for my Youtube channel, which will contain 3D text and the footage from Wrath of The Lich King intro cinematic where Lich King Arhtas stabs the ice with Frostmourne.

I was wondering if there is a tutorial on how to implement 3D Text so it appears from the crack in the ice and after that blurring the video except that text? If you guys can show me some tutorial on that it will be much helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to do. You can use a mask and vignette to make it appear faded or on the ice. With a layer over the 3D text to make it blend better with the layer it's on. To fade the background and not the text just apply a Gaussian blur to the video.

Comment: You can also shrink it real small and have it grow up out of the crack first